# Who or What is the "beast beneath the boards"?

Tags: house-of-the-dragon

Helaena Targaryen made several prophecies throughout season 1, most of which are self explanatory:

> "It has eyes, though I don’t believe it can see."

Referring to the willful blindness of both King Viserys and Queen Alicient towards their children.

> "He’ll have to close an eye."

Referring to the eye Aemond Targaryen had to lose to gain his dragon.

> "Hand turns loom; spools of green, spools of black; dragons of flesh weaving dragons of thread."

Referring to the *hand* of the king, Otto Hightower turning the spool of war between the "greens" who support Aegon's claim to the throne, and the blacks who support Rynerya's claim.

The last and most cryptic prophecy:

> "Beware the beast beneath the boards."

doesn't seem to have a clear answer.

**Who, or what, is the "beast beneath the boards?**

P.S. don't tell me it refers to Rhaenys and her dragon, Meleys, breaking through the ground of the Grand Sept at Aegon’s coronation.  That scene was utter nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

There are many discussions about that over the internet. Most of them try and explain *who* might be concerned and *why*. None of them actually focus on the *meaning* itself only.

> Suddenly your adversary's checker disappears beneath the board, and the problem is to place yours nearest to where his will appear again. Sometimes he would come up unexpectedly on the opposite side of me, having apparently passed directly under the boat.<sup>1</sup>

That prophecy, like many of them ([Nostradamus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostradamus) or [Pythia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythia)) is often very obscure and/or two-faced. In this case, Helaena says that you should be careful because a beast (read: *evil person*) hides itself somewhere close to you and waiting for an opportunity to strike. Once in a while, it may show up, just to check if it's time to attack. And because it's *under the board* (means a piece you can't see), you won't be suspicious enough.

To me, until that plot is revealed, it's there only to add mystery. It leaves doors open so that the story may take any turn, anytime. It's a plot-twist teaser.

---

Read also: [Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/helaena-beware-beast-beneath-boards-prophecy-meaning-theories/) or [Twinfinite](https://twinfinite.net/guides/what-is-the-beast-beneath-the-boards-house-of-the-dragon/) or [Today](https://www.today.com/popculture/tv/helaena-targaryen-prophecies-dreamer-house-of-the-dragon-rcna52762)

---

<sup>1. [Walden and Civil Disobedience - H.D. Thoreau](http://www.literaturepage.com/read/walden-177.html) also mentioned [here - page 154-155](https://theses.hal.science/tel-01789005/document) as part of a English/French thesis</sup>